# Certificate validating functions on Win32

Tags: winapi, ssl, https

I was looking for the sequence of function calls which would need to be made in order to validate a certificate made as part of an https connection and I encountered [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm curious if the APIs offered by MS do hostname validation on certificates. Or is this left upto the developer?